# Conditional Sitecore Form

Tags: sitecore-forms

There are many documents on Sitecore Form's Fields condition or adding or showing or hide Form fields based on condition.

I have a multipage Sitecore Form and i want to make the pages conditional,e.g if an user is already logged in ,it will open page 2 of the multipage form else page 1.
OR
A different form will be opened based on user login condition.

Is there a way to accomplish the same. How can we show a form or a form page based on certain condition?

Answer (score 0):

If you have different forms, you could use personalisation (with the rules engine) on the mvc form rendering to set the correct form based on the condition if a user is logged in or not.

This is an ootb solution, outside of the Forms part itself. It does require 2 forms however which might be an issue. Although you could use a Form template to have a base for both.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to have on the first page of the form two sections :

1. first one for anonymous users
2. second one for logged users.

You can use forms rules condition to hide/show the sections if the users is logged/anonymous.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Gatogordo. You will need to create multiple Forms with pages for anonymous/logged-in users. In fact this will also take care of your requirement of different form for a logged-in user. Please see below:

[image]

Comment: If you agree with `Gatogordo` don't add another answer saying the same thing, upvote the answer you agree with.

Comment: Indeed. Please take the tour, to familiarise yourself with the site and its workings. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/tour